# Windows StorPort spinning up offline drives every 65 minutes

Tags: windows, hard-drive, smart

I have a mini-server running Windows 10 with 1 SSD and 3 Hard-Drives.
I plan to use 2 of the drives scarcely so I want them to stay spun down. I even put them offline inside Disk Management. But the offline drives kept spinning up and then spinning down.

But I tracked it down to Microsoft-Windows-Storage-Storport writing the following in the Event Log:

```
==================================================
Event Time        : 09-Jul-17 4:36:37 PM.041
Record ID         : 14052
Event ID          : 505
Level             : Information
Channel           : Microsoft-Windows-Storage-Storport/Operational
Provider          : Microsoft-Windows-StorPort
Description       : Performance summary for Storport Device (Port = 1, Path = 0, Target = 0, Lun = 0) whose Corresponding Class Disk Device Guid is {069B6C41-FA99-DA5F-4FC2-6BA20AFF7E67}:                 
For latency buckets of 2ms, 64ms, 2048ms, 5120ms, 5120+ms, the IO counts are 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.
Opcode            : 
Task              : Port (201)
Keywords          : Read request
Process ID        : 
Thread ID         : 
==================================================

==================================================
Event Time        : 09-Jul-17 4:36:37 PM.041
Record ID         : 14053
Event ID          : 504
Level             : Information
Channel           : Microsoft-Windows-Storage-Storport/Operational
Provider          : Microsoft-Windows-StorPort
Description       : Error summary for Storport Device (Port = 1, Path = 0, Target = 0, Lun = 0) whose Corresponding Class Disk Device Guid is {069B6C41-FA99-DA5F-4FC2-6BA20AFF7E67}:                     
There were 1 total errors seen and 0 timeouts.                     
The last error seen had opcode 0x85 and completed with SrbStatus 0x1 and ScsiStatus 0x0.                     
The sense code was (0x0,0x0,0x0).                     
The latency was 0 ms.
Opcode            : 
Task              : Port (201)
Keywords          : Read request
Process ID        : 
Thread ID         : 
==================================================

==================================================
Event Time        : 09-Jul-17 4:36:37 PM.041
Record ID         : 14054
Event ID          : 505
Level             : Information
Channel           : Microsoft-Windows-Storage-Storport/Operational
Provider          : Microsoft-Windows-StorPort
Description       : Performance summary for Storport Device (Port = 1, Path = 1, Target = 0, Lun = 0) whose Corresponding Class Disk Device Guid is {E0198DC6-C3AD-2038-E67A-CC5C128C7924}:                 
For latency buckets of 2ms, 64ms, 2048ms, 5120ms, 5120+ms, the IO counts are 25355, 2037, 21, 0, 0.
Opcode            : 
Task              : Port (201)
Keywords          : Read request
Process ID        : 
Thread ID         : 
==================================================

==================================================
Event Time        : 09-Jul-17 4:36:37 PM.041
Record ID         : 14055
Event ID          : 504
Level             : Information
Channel           : Microsoft-Windows-Storage-Storport/Operational
Provider          : Microsoft-Windows-StorPort
Description       : Error summary for Storport Device (Port = 1, Path = 1, Target = 0, Lun = 0) whose Corresponding Class Disk Device Guid is {E0198DC6-C3AD-2038-E67A-CC5C128C7924}:                     
There were 6 total errors seen and 0 timeouts.                     
The last error seen had opcode 0x85 and completed with SrbStatus 0x1 and ScsiStatus 0x0.                     
The sense code was (0x0,0x0,0x0).                     
The latency was 0 ms.
Opcode            : 
Task              : Port (201)
Keywords          : Read request
Process ID        : 
Thread ID         : 
==================================================

==================================================
Event Time        : 09-Jul-17 4:36:37 PM.041
Record ID         : 14056
Event ID          : 505
Level             : Information
Channel           : Microsoft-Windows-Storage-Storport/Operational
Provider          : Microsoft-Windows-StorPort
Description       : Performance summary for Storport Device (Port = 0, Path = 0, Target = 0, Lun = 0) whose Corresponding Class Disk Device Guid is {3F18DCBD-5785-73C0-C528-91E4E8B4C95A}:                 
For latency buckets of 2ms, 64ms, 2048ms, 5120ms, 5120+ms, the IO counts are 56872, 105, 0, 0, 0.
Opcode            : 
Task              : Port (201)
Keywords          : Read request
Process ID        : 
Thread ID         : 
==================================================

==================================================
Event Time        : 09-Jul-17 4:36:37 PM.041
Record ID         : 14057
Event ID          : 504
Level             : Information
Channel           : Microsoft-Windows-Storage-Storport/Operational
Provider          : Microsoft-Windows-StorPort
Description       : Error summary for Storport Device (Port = 0, Path = 0, Target = 0, Lun = 0) whose Corresponding Class Disk Device Guid is {3F18DCBD-5785-73C0-C528-91E4E8B4C95A}:                     
There were 8 total errors seen and 0 timeouts.                     
The last error seen had opcode 0x85 and completed with SrbStatus 0x1 and ScsiStatus 0x0.                     
The sense code was (0x0,0x0,0x0).                     
The latency was 0 ms.
Opcode            : 
Task              : Port (201)
Keywords          : Read request
Process ID        : 
Thread ID         : 
==================================================

==================================================
Event Time        : 09-Jul-17 4:36:37 PM.041
Record ID         : 14058
Event ID          : 505
Level             : Information
Channel           : Microsoft-Windows-Storage-Storport/Operational
Provider          : Microsoft-Windows-StorPort
Description       : Performance summary for Storport Device (Port = 0, Path = 1, Target = 0, Lun = 0) whose Corresponding Class Disk Device Guid is {E38A0FC1-389B-3ADA-FED0-2978A2A6C019}:                 
For latency buckets of 2ms, 64ms, 2048ms, 5120ms, 5120+ms, the IO counts are 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.
Opcode            : 
Task              : Port (201)
Keywords          : Read request
Process ID        : 
Thread ID         : 
==================================================

==================================================
Event Time        : 09-Jul-17 4:36:37 PM.041
Record ID         : 14059
Event ID          : 504
Level             : Information
Channel           : Microsoft-Windows-Storage-Storport/Operational
Provider          : Microsoft-Windows-StorPort
Description       : Error summary for Storport Device (Port = 0, Path = 1, Target = 0, Lun = 0) whose Corresponding Class Disk Device Guid is {E38A0FC1-389B-3ADA-FED0-2978A2A6C019}:                     
There were 1 total errors seen and 0 timeouts.                     
The last error seen had opcode 0x85 and completed with SrbStatus 0x1 and ScsiStatus 0x0.                     
The sense code was (0x0,0x0,0x0).                     
The latency was 0 ms.
Opcode            : 
Task              : Port (201)
Keywords          : Read request
Process ID        : 
Thread ID         : 
==================================================

==================================================
Event Time        : 09-Jul-17 4:36:37 PM.065
Record ID         : 14060
Event ID          : 510
Level             : Information
Channel           : Microsoft-Windows-Storage-Storport/Operational
Provider          : Microsoft-Windows-StorPort
Description       : SMART statistics for Storport Device (Port = 0, Path = 0x0, Target = 0x0, Lun = 0x0).                    
Corresponding Class Disk Device Guid is {3F18DCBD-5785-73C0-C528-91E4E8B4C95A}.
Opcode            : 
Task              : Port (201)
Keywords          : Device state
Process ID        : 4
Thread ID         : 5428
==================================================

==================================================
Event Time        : 09-Jul-17 4:36:37 PM.079
Record ID         : 14061
Event ID          : 511
Level             : Information
Channel           : Microsoft-Windows-Storage-Storport/Operational
Provider          : Microsoft-Windows-StorPort
Description       : ATA Device Statistics Logs for Storport Device (Port = 0, Path = 0x0, Target = 0x0, Lun = 0x0).                    
Corresponding Class Disk Device Guid is {3F18DCBD-5785-73C0-C528-91E4E8B4C95A}.
Opcode            : 
Task              : Port (201)
Keywords          : Device state
Process ID        : 4
Thread ID         : 5428
==================================================

==================================================
Event Time        : 09-Jul-17 4:36:37 PM.119
Record ID         : 14062
Event ID          : 510
Level             : Information
Channel           : Microsoft-Windows-Storage-Storport/Operational
Provider          : Microsoft-Windows-StorPort
Description       : SMART statistics for Storport Device (Port = 1, Path = 0x1, Target = 0x0, Lun = 0x0).                    
Corresponding Class Disk Device Guid is {E0198DC6-C3AD-2038-E67A-CC5C128C7924}.
Opcode            : 
Task              : Port (201)
Keywords          : Device state
Process ID        : 4
Thread ID         : 3368
==================================================

==================================================
Event Time        : 09-Jul-17 4:36:37 PM.449
Record ID         : 14063
Event ID          : 511
Level             : Information
Channel           : Microsoft-Windows-Storage-Storport/Operational
Provider          : Microsoft-Windows-StorPort
Description       : ATA Device Statistics Logs for Storport Device (Port = 1, Path = 0x1, Target = 0x0, Lun = 0x0).                    
Corresponding Class Disk Device Guid is {E0198DC6-C3AD-2038-E67A-CC5C128C7924}.
Opcode            : 
Task              : Port (201)
Keywords          : Device state
Process ID        : 4
Thread ID         : 3368
==================================================
```

Those sets of events happen every 65 minutes in the logs and the hard drives wake up every time they happen. I suspect the driver is querying the SMART data and some drives spin up when SMART data is requested.

If there any way to prevent this from happening? Maybe some idea of what I should try?

The motherboard is Asrock J3160DC-ITX. The problem occurs no matter if my drives are connected to the 2 'normal' SATA ports or the 2 ports from ASMedia ASM1061c controller.

EDIT: Doing further tracing points me to storport.sys!StorpDeviceHealthWorkItemRoutine
It seems to be the worker method that is waking up my drives.

Answer (score 5):

To fix it, you need to add the following keys and values to the Windows Registry:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\StorPort]
"TelemetryPerformanceEnabled"=dword:00000000
"TelemetryErrorDataEnabled"=dword:00000000
"TelemetryDeviceHealthEnabled"=dword:00000000
```

After adding them my drives stopped spinning up.

I found these by decompiling the storport.sys driver. They only seem to be used for event logging so disabling them should cause no issues.
The health and performance logging were set to run every 60 minutes + 5 minutes acceptable delay, explaining why the drives would wake up exactly every 65 minutes.

Comment: I have the same issue as you, but those registry edits did not help in my case - maybe because I still have the drives online in a RAID1. Do you have any idea whether there are other options I could change? Or can you tell me how you decompiled the driver so I can check myself? (PS: I restarted the computer after making the edits, and there are still the same number of events logged every 65 minutes when the drives spin up)

Comment: Maybe it's a different version? Mine is FileVersion: 10.0.15063.332. I used IDA Pro to look at the file, which is unfortunately not free.

Comment: I'm not sure why it didn't work, double check the path and make sure the type is DWORD and value 0. Maybe try adding a QWORD "LogControlEnable" with value 0. I believe that disables all logging. Finally, probably not related but I also ran O&O ShutUp10 before everything and that disabled a significant amount of tracing and logging.

Comment: Thank you, LogControlEnable seems to have done the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've tried everything here and other places with no luck. My HDD was waking every hour for 5 minutes and then going back to sleep. I happened to check the reliability monitor and noticed that I was getting a full system crash with an unexpected shutdown every night at around 2AM caused by AI Suite, the ASUS motherboard software. I was using it for undervolting, underclocking and slowing fan/pump speeds beyond what was possible in the bios.

But after uninstalling that software and every other ASUS service that was running on my system the HDD finally stayed asleep. After weeks of troubleshooting, this was a crazy discovery. It seems to stay asleep for the entire day although it may wake at night to perform update and malware scans, not sure. Waking once a day is no problem for me though.

Hope that is helpful info for someone.